# Error: "Command "..." failed with error code 1 in "..." " when trying to install the qutip package in Canopy using pip

Tags: python, command, installation, pip, canopy

Currently I'm trying to install the qutip package in Canopy using pip. To do so, I'm running the pip installer in the Canopy 64-bit command prompt. 
However, towards the end of each installation attempt I receive an error message that I simply do not understand.

I uploaded screenshots of the command prompt output [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kuxdo.jpg). The last picture contains the cryptical error message.

Here is the error message again:

```
    Command ""C:\Users\NumPhys'14\Canopy\User\Scripts\python.exe" -c "import   
setuptools,tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\numphy~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-
build-dssicp\\qutip\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)
(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record 
c:\users\numphy~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-opo5nk-record\install-record.txt --single-version
-externally-managed --compile --install-headers"C:\Users\NumPhys'14\Canopy\User\
include\site\python2.7\qutip"" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\numphy~1\appdata\local\
temp\pip-build-dssicp\qutip
```

After having implemented the steps from the article linked below I receive a different error message:

```
Found executable C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0
\VC\Bin\a   md64\cl.exe
cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/W3' with '/w'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-ffast-math'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-O3'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-march=native'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-mfpmath=sse'
spmatfuncs.c
c:\users\numphys'14\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\n
py_1_7_deprecated_api.h(12) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable i
t by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
qutip\cy\spmatfuncs.c(355) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'c
omplex.h': No such file or directory
error: Command "cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Users\NumPh
ys'14\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\NumPhys'14\Can
opy\User\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\NumPhys'14\Canopy\User\
lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\NumPhys'14\AppData\Local\Enthoug
ht\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.2.2785.win-x86_64\include -IC:\Users\NumPhys'14
\Canopy\User\PC /Tcqutip\cy\spmatfuncs.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\qut
ip\cy\spmatfuncs.obj -w -ffast-math -O3 -march=native -mfpmath=sse" failed with
exit status 2

----------------------------------------
Command ""C:\Users\NumPhys'14\Canopy\User\Scripts\python.exe" -c "import set
uptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\numphy~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build
-7gmdt0\\qutip\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__)
.read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\num
phy~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-6yzzx6-record\install-record.txt --single-version-e
xternally-managed --compile --install-headers "C:\Users\NumPhys'14\Canopy\User\i
nclude\site\python2.7\qutip"" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\numphy~1\appd
ata\local\temp\pip-build-7gmdt0\qutip
```

Ok, I simply deleted the file "npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h". Now I'm back with the exact same original error message. It seems that it somehow doesn't recognize my Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: Put the information in the question, not on an external link. Also, don't post screenshots of text, just post the text.

Comment: Embed what things return in your question, not necessarily just a link to an image.

Comment: Hm, ok. So I'm going to type the error message.

Comment: It's not legibly formatted.

Comment: This article seems relevant, since it seems that you don't have a required MS C compiler installed. https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469260-Building-Python-extensions-with-Canopy

Comment: Thank you for your help! I re-formatted the error message.
I implemented every step according to the article. Unfortunately, I still receive an error, but at least a different one. I'm including it in the original post.